# Preserve enter animation after changing screen orientation

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, tablet, screen-orientation

I am developing an app supported by smartphones and tablets. For smartphones, the screen orientation is set to portrait (in the Manifest) and for tablets the orientation is changed to landscape programatically.

**The problem**: If I change the orientation programatically the activity's enter animation that I set before with the Intent disappears. How can I keep the screen animation?

I have also tried to override the screen animation inside `onCreate`:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);


    this.phone = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_orientation);

    if(phone){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }else{
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.Animation_activity_slide_left;

    }
}
```

Manifest tags for the activity:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|locale|layoutDirection|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try putting your request orientation code before super.oncreate()

Comment: It's not working either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue I removed the `screenOrientation="portrait` from the manifest and I handled the orientation only programatically in on activity's `onCreate`